# Change string in python using a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I currently have a dictionary of morse code letters, and i want to be able to change a user input string into corresponding morse code characters. Is there any easy way to accomplish this in python?

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Answer (score 6):

```
morse = {"A": ".-", "B": "-...", "C": "-.-."} #etc.
text = "ABC"
output = " ".join(morse[letter] for letter in text)
```

You might want to use `letter.upper()` if input can also be lowercased. And if you don't have all morse characters in your table, you might want to compensate for that, too (credits go to ThiefMaster for this!), so the end result could be

```
output = " ".join(morse[letter] for letter in text.upper() if letter in morse)
```

Comment: Your test also needs to be `if letter.upper() in morse` otherwise lowercase won't be translated.

Answer (score 2):

```
newStr = ' '.join(morseDict[c] for c in oldStr if c in morseDict)
```

This will silently delete all chars which are not keys in `morseDict`

Edit: now adding whitespace between the "letters". You'll want to map `' '` to e.g. a tab or multiple spaces to have a word separator.

Answer (score 0):

```
morse = {
"a": ".-",
"b": "-...",
"c": "-.-.",
...
...
}

str = "Hello"

for ch in str:
    print morse[ch.lower()],
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy:

```
input = 'a string'
morse_code = { ... }

print ' '.join( [morse_code[i] for i in input] )
```

Comment: @eumiro I didn't get your comment.

Comment: run your code (with two or three letters in the `morse_code` dictionary) and you will see. `''.join(...)` joins the elements without space between them. The spaces between letters in the Morse code are important. Replace `''.join` with `' '.join`